# Cant set CORS using sails js for google maps geo location

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cors, sails.js

I am having a hard time trying to enable CORS in my local app. I have been following the documentation of sails.js and all i have to do is change this setting "allRoutes: true" to enable cors. Then when i try to use the google API using angular.

```
getLocation: function(val) {
    return $http.get('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
        params: { address: val, sensor: false }
    });
}
```

I get the following error in my chrome console:
OPTIONS http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=an&sensor=false 
(index):1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=ui&sensor=false. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:1337' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.

Hope anyone have a solution for this. Regards.

Comment: Do you have an angular interceptor that is adding headers to the request? ***sails.js has nothing to do with this.***

Comment: Hi Kevin. i have added this settings in my angular config as it clearly says in the docs.  .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
}])

Comment: i don't see what cors has to with angular, or what sails config has to do with google's server...

Comment: Can you post an image of the request (in chrome's dev tools -> network tab) so we can see all the headers that get sent up?

Comment: Sure. http://i.imgur.com/Fll4USK.png

Comment: That is interesting. Basically chrome is issuing the pre-flight request (OPTIONS) but the server is saying 405 method not allowed meaning it doesn't actually accept the OPTIONS request. So, try removing the $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain (or setting it to false) and see if chrome doesn't issue the pre-flight.

Comment: Also try setting the content type to 'text/plain' or 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' so that it is deemed a 'simple request' and wont issue the pre-flight.

Comment: Nop. I have removed $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain setting and i still get the pre-flight request

Comment: @user1763639 Try the content type, that will sort it.

Comment: So as you said i changed my request to this return $http({url: 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', method: "GET", data: { address: val, sensor: false }, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }});  Still getting pre-flight request

Comment: This http://jsfiddle.net/dqcpa/18/ works quiet fine so as i stated in my question. Isnt this a sails issue?

Comment: @user1763639 Odd, I'm out of ideas. Can't see it being a sails issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing this chrome browser plugin on the Chrome store and Enable cross-origin resource sharing in the options.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

***Edit:***

You endpoint may look something like this:

Firstly do:

```
npm install request
```

Then:

In **config/routes.js** setup your route:

```
'get /location/:keyword': {
     controller: 'location',
     action: "getlocation"
},
```

Then create a controller in **api/controllers** named **LocationController.js**

Inside LocationController.js setup your getlocation action.

```
var request = require('request');
module.exports = {
    getLocation: function(req, res) {
        var keyword = req.param('keyword');
        var url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=' + keyword;
        request(url, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                 res.jsonp({result : body});
            }
        });
    }
};
```

You can then make calls to your own end point which the server will return you the JSON from google API, bypassing the CORS issue.

***GET : localhost:1337/location/california***

Hope this helps.

Richard.

Comment: Thanks Richard but i have also tried this solution and i still get the same console error.

Comment: Can you setup a new endpoint on your Sails.js application, then route the request through there?

**'GET /location/:address'**

Then use Node.js _request_ module to make the call server side and return the results?  If you need an example, just ask.

Comment: Can you set up an example pls?

Comment: could be something in angular- but also check out this example cors config: https://gist.github.com/mikermcneil/3e1bd86b7cca40fb4214

Comment: This is the only solution i see available as i dont find any way to access to the google api through my angular endpoint . Thanks Richard!